# Changes in Azure host windows-latest in August 2022?

Tags: azure-pipelines

Has something changed in `windows-latest`?

On 4th August my pipeline was working but having had a week off I have returned to find that the `dotnet pack` step is now failing.

```
...
   6:7>Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\Company.OtherProduct\Company.OtherProduct.csproj" (_GetProjectVersion target(s)).
     1>Done executing task "MSBuild".
     1>Done building target "_GetProjectReferenceVersions" in project "Company.Product.csproj".
       Target "_InitializeNuspecRepositoryInformationProperties" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(SourceControlInformationFeatureSupported)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('' == 'true').
     1>Target "GenerateNuspec" in file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\buildCrossTargeting\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets" from project "D:\a\1\s\Company.Product\Company.Product.csproj" (target "Pack" depends on it):
       Building target "GenerateNuspec" completely.
       Output file "D:\a\1\a\pack\Company.Product.1.0.0.nupkg" does not exist.
       Task "ConvertToAbsolutePath" skipped, due to false condition; ($(NuspecFile) != '') was evaluated as ( != '').
       Using "PackTask" task from assembly "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\buildCrossTargeting\..\CoreCLR\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.dll".
       Task "PackTask"
     1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\buildCrossTargeting\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(221,5): error NU5026: The file 'D:\a\1\s\Company.Product\bin\Debug;VersionSuffix=build-pack-fix.2596\net40\Company.Product.dll' to be packed was not found on disk. [D:\a\1\s\Company.Product\Company.Product.csproj]
         NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: The file 'D:\a\1\s\Company.Product\bin\Debug;VersionSuffix=build-pack-fix.2596\net40\Company.Product.dll' to be packed was not found on disk.
            at NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.PackTaskLogic.InitLibFiles(IMSBuildItem[] libFiles, IDictionary`2 aliases)
            at NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.PackTaskLogic.GetPackArgs(IPackTaskRequest`1 request)
            at NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.PackTask.Execute()
       Done executing task "PackTask" -- FAILED.
     1>Done building target "GenerateNuspec" in project "Company.Product.csproj" -- FAILED.
     1>Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\Company.Product\Company.Product.csproj" (pack target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

       "D:\a\1\s\Company.Product\Company.Product.csproj" (pack target) (1) ->
       (GenerateNuspec target) -> 
         C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\buildCrossTargeting\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(221,5): error NU5026: The file 'D:\a\1\s\Company.Product\bin\Debug;VersionSuffix=build-pack-fix.2596\net40\Company.Product.dll' to be packed was not found on disk. [D:\a\1\s\Company.Product\Company.Product.csproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

The project multi-targets `net4.0;net60` and I've tried changing that to `net60` but I get the same problem.

`dotnet pack` is working fine on my desktop.

Before the Azure output had

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.2.0+41abc5629 for .NET
```

and now it has

```
SBuild version 17.3.0+92e077650 for .NET
```

My desktop has VisualStudio 2022 17.2.6.

Comment: Should `$(NuspecFile) != ''` be `'$(NuspecFile)' != ''`?

Comment: Looks like the pack version suffix is being put into the path?

Answer (score 0):

The log showed the `pack` command as

```
[command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" pack D:\a\1\s\Company.Product\Company.Product.csproj --output D:\a\1\a\pack --no-build --include-symbols --include-source "/p:Configuration=Debug;VersionSuffix=\"concept.2597\"" --verbosity Detailed
```

So MS must have stopped treating `;` as some sort of delimiter.

The fix was to change

```
    buildProperties: 'VersionSuffix="$(packVersionSuffix)"'
```

to

```
    arguments: '--version-suffix "$(packVersionSuffix)"'
```

in my pileline yml for the `pack` commdn.

Answer (score 0):

Well that didn't work.
Apparently not all arguments work for all `command`s of the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task.
So back to PowerShell:(

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Detect packable projects'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "A csproj is packable if it contains <VersionPrefix> and <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>."
      $projectsToPack = @()
      $bad = $false
      foreach( $csproj in Get-ChildItem **\*.csproj ) {
          $pkgName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($csproj.FullName)
          echo $pkgName
          
          $m = Select-String -Path $csproj.FullName -Pattern '<VersionPrefix>([\d\.]+)</VersionPrefix>'
          $packable = Select-String -Path $csproj.FullName -Pattern '<IsPackable>[Tt]rue</IsPackable>'
          if( $m.Matches.Count -eq 1 -and $packable.Matches.Success)
          {
              $csprojVersion = $m.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
              echo "  Packable (version prefix is $csprojVersion)."
              $projectsToPack += "$pkgName.csproj"
          }
          elseif ($m.Matches.Count -ne 1 -and $packable.Matches.Success)
          {
            $bad = $true;
            echo "  ERROR: Is packable but invalid VersionPrefix (zero or multiple)."
          }
          elseif ($m.Matches.Success -and $packable.Matches.Success)
          {
            $bad = $true;
            echo "  ERROR: Has VersionPrefix but is not packable."
          }
          else
          {
              echo "  Not packable."
          }
      }

      if( $bad )
      {
        exit 1
      }

      $packList = ($projectsToPack -join ";")
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=projectsToPack]$packList"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=projectsToPush]$packList" # Default: push everything that's packed.

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Require packed projects to reference Microsoft.SourceLink.AzureRepos.Git'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        [string] $sourceLink = 'Include="Microsoft.SourceLink.AzureRepos.Git"'
        [bool] $bad = $false

        Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter '*.csproj' |
            Foreach-Object {
                if( ("${{ parameters.projectsToPack }}").Contains($_.Name) )
                {
                    if( Select-String -Path $_.FullName -Pattern $sourceLink )
                    {
                        # OK
                    }
                    else {
                        $bad = $true
                        echo "$_.Name does not reference Microsoft.SourceLink.AzureRepos.Git"
                    }
                 }
            }
         
        if( $bad ) {
            exit 1
        }
        exit 0
        
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Set version-suffix for dotnet pack'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
          $packVersionSuffix = ""
          if("$(Build.SourceBranchName)" -ne "master")
          {
            $packSourceBranchName = "$(Build.SourceBranchName)" -replace '[^A-Za-z0-9-]+', '-' -replace "^-+|-+$", ""
            $packVersionSuffix = "$packSourceBranchName.$(Build.BuildId)"
          }
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packVersionSuffix]$packVersionSuffix"

     
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Check package version numbers'
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master')
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      [bool] $bad = $false;

      # Token created 2022-05-05 by rwb. Has 1 permission: read packages. Expires 2023-05-04.
      $patToken = "..." | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
      $credsAzureDevopsServices = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("my@somewhere.co.uk", $patToken)

      # Sometimes the pipeline already has source, and sometimes it doesn't!
      Register-PackageSource -Name "FeedForPipeline" -Location "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/Company/_packaging/Feed/nuget/v2" -ProviderName NuGet -Credential $credsAzureDevopsServices

      Get-PackageSource
      
      $projectsToPush = @() # A subset of packable projects -- allows us to no update a csproj version when we haven't made a change in a repo that contains multiple pushable csprojs.
    
      foreach( $csproj in Get-ChildItem **\*.csproj ) { # do do: limit to projectsToPack.
          $pkgName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($csproj.FullName)
          echo $pkgName
          
          $m = Select-String -Path $csproj.FullName -Pattern '<VersionPrefix>([\d\.]+)</VersionPrefix>'
          $packable = Select-String -Path $csproj.FullName -Pattern '<IsPackable>[Tt]rue</IsPackable>'
          if( $m.Matches.Count -eq 1 -and $packable.Matches.Success)
          {
              $csprojVersion = $m.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
              
              $pkg = $null
              try {
                  $pkg = Find-Package $pkgName -Source FeedForPipeline -Credential $credsAzureDevopsServices -ErrorAction Stop
              }
              catch {
                  echo "  Error finding package."
                  $projectsToPush += "$pkgName.csproj" # Maybe it doesn't exist.
                  continue
                  $pkg = $null
              }

              if( $pkg -eq $null )
              {
                  echo "  No existing package."
                  $projectsToPush += "$pkgName.csproj"
                  continue
              }
              $current = $pkg.Version
    
              if( [System.Version]"$csprojVersion" -lt [System.Version]"$current" )
              {
                  echo "  REJECTED: current version is $current but csproj has version $csprojVersion."
                  $bad = $true
              }
              elseif( [System.Version]"$csprojVersion" -eq [System.Version]"$current" )
              {
                  echo "  SKIP: current version is $current but csproj has version $csprojVersion."
              }
              else {
                echo "  $current -> $csprojVersion"
                $projectsToPush += "$pkgName.csproj"
              }
          }
          else {
              echo "  Skipped."
          }
      }
      
      if( $bad ) {
        Write-Warning "Some versions are invalid; failing."
        exit 1
      }
      
      if( $projectsToPush.count -eq 0 ) {
        Write-Warning "No packages can be pushed."
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=projectsToPush]"
        exit 0
      }
      
      $pushList = ($projectsToPush -join ";")
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=projectsToPush]$pushList"
      exit 0

# Pack everything that's packable to check that it packs OK, but remove output that we don't want to push.
# DotNetCoreCLI@2 seems to be pretty broken, so use PowerShell instead :(
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73375348/changes-in-azure-host-windows-latest-in-august-2022/73376196#73376196
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#arguments (arguments dont' work for pack)

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Pack'
  condition: ne(variables['projectsToPack'], '')
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        $packVersionSuffix = '$(packVersionSuffix)'
        $bo = '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' # 'artifact' (sic).

        $projectsToPack = '$(projectsToPack)'.Split(';')
        $projectsToPush = '$(projectsToPush)'.Split(';')

        foreach( $csproj in Get-ChildItem **\*.csproj ) {
            if($projectsToPack.Contains($csproj.Name)) {
                $outputDirectory = "$bo\pack"
                if( -Not $projectsToPush.Contains($csproj.Name)) {
                    $outputDirectory = "$bo\pack_no_push"
                }
                dotnet pack --no-restore --no-build --include-source --include-symbols --version-suffix "$packVersionSuffix" --output "$outputDirectory" "$csproj" # Fuck knows why .FullName not only isn't needed but moreover doesn't work.
            }
        }

        if (Test-Path "$bo\pack_no_push") {
            Remove-Item -Force -Recurse "$bo\pack_no_push"
        }    
# This creates both .nupkg and .symbols.nupkg files
```